# Trouble proving that if $A \approx B$ then $A^C \approx B^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that if $A \approx B$ then $A^C \approx B^C$

According to my textbook, $A^C$ is the set of all functions from $C$ to $A$, ie. $A^C=\{F\in \mathscr P(Y \times X): F$ is a function$\}$.

So I need to prove that there is a function $g: A^C \to B^C$ that is one-one and onto. ie. For one-one, assume $g(h)=g(h')$ where $h$ is a function in $A^C$, and show that $h=h'$. Also assume that there is a $f: A\to B$ that is one-one and onto.

I am stuck because I have no idea how to define $g$; I think this is partly because I am slightly confused by what the definition of $g: A^C \to B^C$ is. I know it is a set of functions, but what exactly does that mean/ what does a member look like? Is it a set of ordered pairs consisting of functions? eg. $<f,g>$?

Also it seems that some info about $C$'s relation to other sets is needed, but is not provided.

Could anyone help or point me at the right direction please?

(Schröder–Bernstein theorem is available, but I am not sure if it will be useful here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically functions can be *modeled* by certain sets of pairs, but that is not a very productive *intuition* about what is going on for your purpose here.

I think it is more fruitful to think of a function $X\to Y$ as a *machine* with the property that when you put an element of $X$ into it, *somehow* an element of $Y$ comes out the other end -- and this happens in a repeatable fashion such that if you put the *same* element of $X$ into the machine multiple times, the *same* element of $Y$ will be produced several times.

When you're looking for a function $g:A^C \to B^C$, then you want to constructs a machine that makes machines into other machines. The input to your $g$ will be a machine $C\to A$. You want use that to produce a machine $C\to B$.

The natural way to do that will be to bolt the $C\to A$ machine you get as input together with a copy of the the $f:A\to B$ you have assumed exists. The combined machine will first use the input to convert the incoming $c$ into an $a$, and then use $f$ to convert the $a$ into a $b$. The net effect is that something from $C$ comes in and something from $B$ comes out -- in other words we do get a function $C\to B$.

Once you have used the machine analogy to work out what your $g$ should *do*, you can go back to symbolic reasoning to try to prove that this $g$ is actually a bijection.

Comment: Thank you that approach is really useful; appreciate it. If I understand correctly, I am supposed to define $g$ to be $f\circ h: A^C\to B^C$ (where $h: C\to A$), and show that if $f(h(c))=f(h(c'))$ then $ c=c'$. But doesn't this mean that the input of $g$ is an element $c \in C$, instead of a function $C\to A$?

Comment: I am also stuck on how to proceed; by the fact that $f$ is one-one, I can prove that $h(c)=h(c')$, but without any info about $h$ (do I have to define it in a specific way?) I can't really prove $c=c'$

Comment: @DanielMak:No, you would define $g(h) = f\circ h$ (not $g=f\circ h$ which is nonsense). And the function you need to prove is a bijection is $g$ itself, not the function that $g$ outputs. In other words, for injectivity you need to prove that  if $g(h_1)=g(h_2)$ then $h_1=h_2$ -- which is to say, if $f\circ h_1$ and $f\circ h_2$ are the same function, then $h_1$and $h_2$ must have been the same function to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Given an element of $A^C,$ it is some map $u:C \to A.$ Then define $g(u):C \to B$ by composition. That is, $g(u)(c)=f(u(c)).$

Answer (score 2):

Since A$\approx$B, there exists a one-to-one onto function f:A$\rightarrow$B. That is the key to the exercise.

Let $\phi\in A^C$. Then f$\circ \phi$:C$\rightarrow$B. So we define a function $\psi_f$:$A^C \rightarrow B^C$ such that  $\phi \mapsto f\circ\phi$.

1:**$\psi_f$ is onto.** Let g$\in B^C$. Then $f^{-1}\circ g \in A^C$. So 
$$\psi_f(f^{-1} \circ g) = f \circ f^{-1} \circ g = g. \checkmark $$

2.**$\psi_f$ is one-to-one.** Suppose $\phi_1,\phi_2 \in A^C$ such that $f \circ \psi_1 = f \circ \psi_2$. Thus for every c $\in$ C, then 
$$f(\psi_1(c)) = f(\psi_2(c))$$
But since f is invertible, that forces 
$$\psi_1(c) = \psi_2(c)\text{  }  \forall c \checkmark$$